# Communication between processes

Tags: python-3.x

What's the simplest way to send a simple string to a process (I know the pid of the process and I don't need to do any check of any sort) in python 3-4 ?

Should I just go for a communication via socket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only two processes communicate, you can use a pipe (it can be named using mkfifo or "anonymous" using pipe & dup syscalls).

If you want one server and some clients, then you can use sockets. TCP socket is usable over network, but on unix/linux exists also so-called "unix socket", that look alike named pipe.

Next way to communicate between applicaitons are realtime signals and/or shared memory.

More information about unix socket: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html
About pipes, google will tell you.

But, to correctly answer your question (which do not have only one "right answer"), I think that simplest is using named pipe, because it is used as writing to file on disk.